# How do I report bugs on unity-webapps-preview?

Tags: bug-reporting, webapps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

I'm interested in reporting a bug against the *unity-webapps-preview* package from *ppa:webapps/preview*.  However, I can't seem to find the right way to go about it.

Things I've tried (and what went wrong):

1. Reporting using ubuntu-bug.  ("The problem cannot be reported: This is not an official Ubuntu package. Please remove any third party package and try again.")
2. Reporting using Launchpad website.  (I can't find a link.  This could be oversight on my part.  Forgive me if it is.)
3. Using Google to figure out how to report bugs against PPAs.  (The only suggestion I could find using Google seems to be to e-mail the developer directly, which I'm willing to do only if there's no better way.)

I would appreciate any advice or insight the Community can give me on how to report a bug of this nature.  Thanks!

Comment: @AnwarShah Nope. This is dealing with reporting bug against a package under testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You are using a package that is not provided in Ubuntu repositories, and hence, `ubuntu-bug` will very likely fail.

However, this is a project that is officially backed by Ubuntu, and is in its testing phase. Usually, [QA Tracker](http://packages.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker) contains a section on such projects.

Head over to [QA Tracker](http://packages.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker) and select `Webapps Precise testing` or `Webapps Quantal Testing` as appropriate. You are highly encouraged to record your feedback by subvmitting a result to as many test cases as possible. Installation, Uninstallation, and Bug reporting instructions are all detailed there.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and pointing me to QA Tracker.  I was unaware that this existed.  :)

Just to clarify, based on the instructions here:
[link](http://packages.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/227/builds/19412/buginstructions)
I should just report any problems in the unity-firefox-extensions package if I'm using Firefox, correct?  Even if I'm not sure that the Firefox extension itself is to blame?

Comment: Yes. If you encounter a bug when using webapps from firefox, blame it on `unity-firefox-extensions`. It would be a great help if you also tried to check if it exists in chrome, and file another bug if it exists. And do report all bugs in QA tracker.